# Run MySQL Query with ü by php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a PHP script assembling this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM `schueler`
WHERE `vorname` = 'Tom' AND
       `nachname` = 'Müller' AND
       passwort = 'danny12'
```

when I try this with phpMyAdmin it works and I get the requested row in return. Though when I run this query with php `mysql_query` then `mysql_num_rows` tells me that no row is returned.

Other querys on the same table do work properly. 
I think there is a problem with the ü.
The row is encoded with `utf8_general_ci`

Chris

Comment: Show your code, please. It would be best if you converted from mysql to mysqli or PDO, since the mysql API is deprecated. Using parametrized queries would probably resolve the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set characters encoding after the `mysql_connect` function like this:

```
mysql_query("set character_set_client='utf8'"); 
mysql_query("set character_set_results='utf8'"); 
mysql_query("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
```

Also notice that the `mysql_` extension is deprecated in PHP 5.5 and you should move to newer and safer extensions such as [`mysqli_`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: I know i was in a hurry and it told me to wait some seconds

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP file must be encoded as UTF-8 too. If you're not sure about the file's encoding, open up Notepad, click "Save as...", and check if the "Encoding" drop down menu is at "UTF-8". Set it to that if not, and save.

In addition to that, you must set the charset of the connection using [mysql_set_charset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php), e.g.

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

Or (better yet) the equivalent in MySQLi or PDO.